# rails with ajax in dynamic select collection

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've dynamic menu and I tried to use `grouped_collection_select`

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :unit_id, Project.visible.order(:position), :units, :name, :id, :full_name, include_blank: true, class: 'items' %>
```

but I don't need to show all `:units` I just need to use thing like that `Unit.visible`, after many tries and searches I decided to ignore this scenario and use ajax but some thing makes my code don't work and this is my code

```
--[ Models ]--------------------------------------------    

        class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
            has_many   :activities
        end     

        class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
            belongs_to :customer
            belongs_to :project
            belongs_to :unit
        end

        class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
            has_many   :units,      dependent: :destroy 
            has_many   :activities
        end

        class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
            belongs_to :project
            has_many   :activities
        end
--------------------------------------------------------        

---[ Controller ]---------------------------------------    

class UnitsController < ApplicationController
  def get_units
    @project = Project.find params[:project_id]
    @units   = @project.units
  end
end
--------------------------------------------------------    

---[ View ]-(new activity)------------------------------
  <%= nested_form_for(@customer, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <div class="nested">
        <% f.fields_for :activities do |activity| %>
            <%= render "activity_call_fields", f: activity %>
        <% end %>

        <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add activity", :activities %></p>
    </div>
  <% end %> 

---(activity_call_fields)-(this is partial)---------------
<div id="id_dynamic_select">
  <%= f.collection_select :project_id, Project.all, :id, :name, include_blank: true, class: 'project_selection' %>
  <%= f.collection_select :unit_id,    Unit.all,    :id, :name, include_blank: true, class: 'unit_selection' %> 
</div>
----------------------------------------------------------

---[ javascript ]---------------------------------------
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready ->
      $("#id_dynamic_select select:nth-child(1)").on "change", ->
        $.ajax
          url: "/units/get_units"
          type: "GET"
          dataType: "script"
          data:
            project_id: $("#id_dynamic_select select:nth-child(1) option:selected").val()

</script>
---(this is partial)-----------------------------------
    $('#id_dynamic_select select:nth-child(2)').empty();
    $('#id_dynamic_select select:nth-child(2)').append( $('<option>Select the unit</option>'));
    <% @units.each do |unit| %>
      $('#id_dynamic_select select:nth-child(2)').append($('<option value="<%= unit.id %>"><%= unit.full_name %></option>'));
    <% end %>
--------------------------------------------------------

---[ route ]--------------------------------------------
resources :units do
    collection do    
      get 'get_units', to: "units#get_units"
    end
  end
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried to use classes  `.project_selection` and `.unit_selection` but I didn't see it in source page only thing like `id="customer_activities_attributes_1451397090634_project_id"`

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, using first scenario `grouped_collection_select`, if you need to use thing like that `Unit.visible` go to your Model `class Project < ActiveRecord::Base` and defined method to return what you are need to show

```
# ===[ Methods ]==============
  def visible_units
    self.units.visible # visible is scope
  end
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

in your view write this code, this worked with me

`<%= f.grouped_collection_select :unit_id, Project.visible.order(:position), :visible_units, :name, :id, :full_name, { :include_blank => true }, { :class=> "select_unit_id" } %>`

Answer (score 0):

When you use remote: true, the form will automatically be submitted via ajax. So you don't need to write the ajax yourself. What you need instead is handle ajax:success ajax:error events :

[form-for doc](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for)